# Insert multiple rows at once with Ecto. "protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Changeset"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two tables. A table of `topics` which `has_many` `tweets`. My table of `tweets` `belongs_to` a `topic`.

Topic Schema:

```
defmodule Sentiment.Topic do
  use Sentiment.Web, :model

  schema "topics" do
    field :title, :string

    has_many :tweets, Sentiment.Tweet
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title])
    |> validate_required([:title])
  end
end
```

Tweet Schema:

```
defmodule Sentiment.Tweet do
  use Sentiment.Web, :model

  schema "tweets" do
    field :message, :string
    belongs_to :topic, Sentiment.Topic

  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:message])
    |> validate_required([:message])
  end
end
```

I am attempting to insert a `topic` into my table, followed by 500 `tweets` after I run a twitter search for that topic.

In my controller, I use `Ecto.Multi` to group my repo operations, however, each time I run my operation I get an error `protocol Enumerable not implemented for #Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{message: "\"aloh....`

This is how I am attempting to insert my topic first, obtain it's id, and then insert a tweet message with the associated id with one transaction.

```
 def create(conn, %{"topic" => topic}) do
    # create a topic changeset
    topic_changeset = Topic.changeset(%Topic{}, topic)

    # obtain a list of tweet messages: ["hello", "a tweet", "sup!"]
    %{"title" => title} = topic
    all_tweets = title
    |> Twitter.search

# create an Ecto.Multi struct.
multi =
  Ecto.Multi.new
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:topics, topic_changeset) #insert topic
  |> Ecto.Multi.run(:tweets, fn %{topics: topic} ->
    changeset_tweets = all_tweets
    |> Enum.map(fn(tweet) ->
      %{topic_id: topic.id, message: tweet}
    end)

    Repo.insert_all(Tweet, changeset_tweets)

  end)

      # Run the transaction
      case Repo.transaction(multi) do # ERROR HERE!
        {:ok, result} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "Success!")
          |> redirect(to: topic_path(conn, :index))
        {:error, :topics, topic_changeset, %{}} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:error, "Uh oh...")
          |> render("new.html", changeset: topic_changeset)
        {:error, :tweets, topic_changeset, %{}} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:error, "Something really bad happened...")
          |>render("new.html", changeset: topic_changeset)
      end
  end
```

How can I `insert_all` about 500 rows in one transaction using Ecto.Multi?

**Update**
I have converted the list of changesets into a list of maps and my error has changed to something even more confusing.

[image: error]
[image: what I am trying to insert]

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace? The error should be in the line containing `Repo.insert_all` since it only supports list of maps and lists of keyword lists, not list of changesets.

Comment: @Dogbert I posted an image of the error for you.

Comment: As @Dogbert said, you are trying to pass in a list of changesets to `Repo.insert_all`. however, that function does not accept a list of changesets. It only takes a list of maps or a list of keyword lists.

Comment: @JustinWood I have created a list of maps, each map containing two properties. `topic_id` and `message`. When I attempt to run the transaction, my error is `no case clause matching: {5, nil}`

Comment: Have you considered to use `cast_assoc(:tweets)` in the topic changeset, instead of performing the same thing manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For [`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#run/3) to properly progress with steps, every one of them has to return either `{:ok, value}` or `{:error, reason}` tuple.

When `insert`ing, `update`ing or `delete`ing a changeset, it will return such a tuple automatically, but for `run`, you need to return it explicitly.

Please, consider the following:

```
Ecto.Multi.new
|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:topics, topic_changeset) #insert topic
|> Ecto.Multi.run(:tweets, fn %{topics: topic} ->
   maps = 
     Enum.map(all_tweets, fn(tweet) ->
       %{topic_id: topic.id, message: tweet}
     end)

    {count, _} = Repo.insert_all(Tweet, maps)
    {:ok, count} # <----
end)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! This helped me a lot. I'm new to phoenix :)

Comment: Ecto.Multi can be used in any Elixir project. This doesn't have to be Phoenix. Just saying! Glad you found it useful!

Comment: I'll be sure to read the docs more carefully next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Alex, this is not a direct answer to your question with `Ecto.Multi`, but a suggestion, that it might be easier to use `cast_assoc(:tweets)` inside your topic changeset.

This would look like this:

```
# Topic.ex
...
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:message])
  |> cast_assoc(:tweets) 
  |> validate_required([:message])
end

# create_topic..
...
tweets = [%{message: "Tweet 1"}, %{message: "Tweet 2"}]

{:ok, topic} = 
  %Topic{}
  |> Topic.changeset(Map.put(topic, :tweets, tweets))
  |> Repo.insert()
```

Comment: I tried this but get a changeset error saying I'm missing the foreign_key ie. topic_id.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of now (2021) Ecto 3 provides the function [`Multi.insert_all`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#insert_all/5) already, so that one wouldn't need to use `Multi.run` manually in this scenario.